# Copying a local SQL Server database (not on Azure)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2012

To back up my SQL Azure database periodically I have been using the simple tSQL statement

```
CREATE DATABASE FiveModes10_12_12 AS COPY OF FiveModes
```

But for this project (analysing some experimental results) my database is a local SQL Server 2012 one and I cannot run that statement (I get the error `Incorrect syntax near 'COPY'`). Looking at [the documentation for the `CREATE DATABASE` command for SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) there is no `AS COPY OF` option. What is the simplest alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For long lived copies take e database backup instead:

```
backup database FiveModes to disk = 'path to .bak file' with init, copy_only;
```

You can the restore this when needed:

```
restore database FiveMode from disk = 'path to .bak file';
```

You can even restore the backup as a new database, but you'll need to move the location of the MDF/LDF files during the restore:

```
restore database FiveMode_12_12 from disk = 'path to .bak file'
   with move 'FiveMode' to '<path to place the new copy of MDF>',
   move 'FiveMode_log' to '<path to place the new copy of LDF>'
```

If you need only  short lived copy (eg. create a copy, do some experiment, revert to the copy) you can use database snapshots, but it requires Enterprise license. See [Database Snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx):

```
create database FiveModes10_12_12  on
  (Name = 'FiveMode', FileName = '<path to MDF snapshot file>')
as snapshot of FiveModes;
```

But be aware that snapshots are not at all like Azure copies, is very detrimental to keep them along for long time. For long time copies use backups.

Comment: Thanks Remus, I'll use .bak. And +1 for pointing out the performance difficulties with snapshots, I was thinking about using them.